# android platform is not adding in Cordova project - java environment error

Tags: android, cordova

when adding android platform to my cordova project i am getting this error

Error: failed to run 'java -version', make sure your java environment is set up including jdk and jre
your JAVA_HOME variable is c:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin
Error: Command failed: 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

while i have set JAVA and JAVA_HOME variable in systemVariable.
JAVA      C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin
JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45
and in Path i have set this
**“;%JAVA_HOME%\bin”**;%ANT_HOME%\bin;;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;**%JAVA%\bin;**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to set `JAVA_HOME` environment variable Not JAVA..
And in 'PATH' add `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` ..

Then test `java -version` command in cmd first if its working then try to run cordova build command.

see this [doc](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html) for more detail..

Comment: Error resolved:-) but new error found;( now i am getting this please install android target 19 (the android newest sdk). make sure you have the latest andriod tools installed as well . Run "androir" from your command line to install update any missing sdk or tools

Comment: so add android sdk 'tools' & 'platform-tools' to PATH then run android command and update sdk tools also download api 19(kitkat) platform..

Comment: i have added ANDRIOD_HOME C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk and i have added in Path %ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools and Andriod sdk build tools 19 installed

Comment: if 'android' command is working fine then update sdk build tools to latest & install platform-19..